# What could be right words for delicate issue as in speaking

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Recently a fellow colleague unintentionally made fun or made wrong choice of words against someone's caste/ethnicity.

One fellow responded and asked him to behave or he might get hurt someday using such words because people take it rather seriously. And it's inappropriate to say something funny/bad about such topics.

What could be right sentence or word for the following in English.
"critical issues, must be treated/talked about carefully"

Comment: A common term would be sensitivity (exercising sensitivity or talking with sensitivity or being sensitive to the issue or people's feelings).

Comment: Good explanation, `exercise sensitivity before talking`, I hope to see more answers to understand better.

Comment: This is a very American phrase and sometimes has sarcastic/negative connotations, but we also say, "Please be more 'PC' when speaking about such sensitive topics." PC = [Politically correct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_correctness).

Comment: I do not know what idea you are trying to convey with **caste/authenticity**.  I do not understand the joining of the two words with a slash. The two words seem unrelated to each other.

Comment: "exercise sensitivity" is a strange phrase to my ears.  **Be sensitive** is idiomatic.

Comment: @TRomano My English is not good. The word is a mistake I assume. Not Authenticity. I meant the background country of ancestors.

Comment: "Sensitive issues must be discussed respectfully" (i.e. with respect for the people you are talking about)

Comment: @Peter your comment seems pretty clear and easy for me to say n remember. Thanks

Comment: @PeterMorris If you can add your comment as answer then I'll select that as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Sensitive issues must be discussed respectfully" (i.e. with respect for the people you are talking about)